# pyplot how to hide the small scale when set scale is log

Tags: matplotlib

I set the scale of `Y` to `log`:

```
plt.yscale('log')
```

But I want remove the smaller scale in `y` axis, and only keep the 10^k (k is integer) on the scale. How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The small lines on the y-axis are called `minorticks` in matplotlib parlance.

You can turn them off with

```
plt.minorticks_off()
```